# MongoDB: $or operator error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use `$or` operator but it's returns a error.

My code:

```
{db.hw1_1.find( { "name": { $in: ["kamatchi","kamala"] } } )
```

It's returning answer. But this query returning error.

```
{db.hw1_1.find( { "name": { $or: ["kamatchi","kamala"] } } )
```

Returns:

```
error: {
 $err: "can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $or   ",
"code" : 1787
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator basically is an **or** condition but just in a specialized way. So you can use it as a short form to test a list of values either as some type of object or a regular expression.

On the other hand [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is more terse, so this would be the same as the `$in` query

```
db.hw1_1.find({ $or: [{ "name": "kamatchi" }, { "name": "kamala"} ] } )
```

So `$in` is best to test multiple values against a single key. Think of `$or` as a "list of queries" that are treated separately and only one of those queries needs to be satisfied.